# php- echo not displaying from database

Tags: php, html

I have a database in 'test' called 'leaderboard'... fields are 'id, name,g-b_ratio'

my code....

```
    <div class="leaderboard">
<?php
mysql_select_db("test")  or die("Cannot select the database");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM leaderboard") or die("Cannot select the database");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)); 
{
echo $row['name']; } ?>

      </div>
```

is not displaying anything from database.

why is it happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you realize there is a semicolon after your while() statement?

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)); 
{
echo $row['name']; }
```

I imagine it iterates to the last row before the echo is ever reached.  Remove that semicolon and try again?

Comment: Glad I could help.  I do this kind of shit all the time, I know how frustrating it is not being able to find something so simple

Answer (score 2):

- $row['name'] is empty
- there are no rows in leaderboard table
- you can try something like

--

```
if (!mysql_num_rows($result)){
   echo "There are no rows in leaderboard table";
}
```

Comment: there is this in the 'leaderboard' table as ive checked and checked spelling is same in code and table

Comment: try to remove  `!`and tell me what does it output

Comment: i removed it and it displayed the echo... but i dont understand im looking at the table now and it's not empty?!?!?!?!?!

Comment: are you sure "name" column exists?

Comment: i deleted and nothing stilled display... i dont understand im looking at the 'leaderboard' table and it has all the fields and when i go 'browse' it has something there?

Comment: browse in phpmyadmin on the 'leaderboard' table

Comment: can you print it out the div ... maybe there is a display:none on that div ... var_dump or echo with exit ;

Comment: aah. try to replace your while with `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)); 
{
print_r($row); }` - does it show something? Or try to look at your html source - is there something?

Comment: when putting that code in it does not show anything! what do you mean by look at your html source? This is crazy! im 100% there is something in the database

Comment: try to use this <div class="leaderboard" style="display:block;"> ,, and try to var_dump the $row variable .

Comment: also outside of the <div> it still does not display

Comment: ok can you this :

`<?php
mysql_select_db("test")  or die("Cannot select the database");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM leaderboard") or die("Cannot select the database");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)); 
{
var_dump($row); 
exit();
}
?>`

Comment: i added and it displayed 'bool(false) '

Comment: @genesis what else could be going wrong? is it a database problem?

Answer (score -1):

Use `mysql_fetch_assoc($result)`.

In this way you can call `$row['name']`.

Comment: it won't help as mysql_fetch_array gives the same + array with numeric indexes

Comment: you can call $row['name'] with _array too. _array is for both, _assoc is for associative and _row is for numeric indexes

Comment: in <?php
include("config.php");
?>

Comment: `mysql_select_db("test")  or die("Cannot select the database");`
if he's not connected, this will fail, too